# How to cast uint256 to varchar in DuneSQL?

Tags: dune, dune-analytics

How to cast uint256 to varchar in DuneSQL?

Here is an [example query](https://dune.com/queries/2964024)

Here is an output

```
Error: Line 36:11: Cannot cast array(uint256) to uint256 at line 36, position 11 [Execution ID: 01H8J5X9M7BKXB59N0ZFYS4F7J]
```

#dune

Answer (score -1):

If the query is

```
SELECT 
  id,
  cast(id as varchar) 
FROM 
  erc1155_ethereum.evt_TransferSingle
LIMIT 1;
```

it simply runs without errors